# How to open a PDF from iCloud

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf, icloud

I have an application for iPad that needs get PDF and videos from iCloud, open the PDF in a webview, then save the index path in a doc that will then need to open it in another view and and save in doc.

So far I can open iCloud and download with this code:

```
(IBAction)openIcloud:(id)sender {

    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

    documentPicker.delegate = self;

    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve, perhaps with an example?

Comment: I can open iCloud from my app. I can see all documents on iCloud  PDF, videos, imagen  and I can download them. but I do not know how to open the pdf  download in a simple webview

Answer (score 0):

you're very close it just lacks something like this

```
#pragma mark - iCloud files
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller   didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
  if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {


  docController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url];
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentPickerMode];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [MywebWiev setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [MywebWiev setDelegate:self];
    MywebWiev.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [MywebWiev loadRequest:requestObj];

}

}

 - (IBAction)Pdf001:(id)sender {
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker =   [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]   inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

documentPicker.delegate = self;

documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];


}

 remember call <UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Happy conding